# rails mongoid 2 pass db connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

We have  situation where we want to have a 2 pass config for mongo connection from our rails app, is there a way to do this with a combination of mongoid.yml and maybe an application initializer. What we want to happen is have this in our mongoid.yml:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: data_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:

production_2:
  clients:
    default:
      database: data_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        user: special
        password: ENV['DB_PASSWORD']
```

What we want to happen is to try to connect to production, but if authentication fails, fall back to an env variable.  My questions are:

1. Can this be done with one db (can production have a pecking order, try this if it fails try that)
2. Can the yml file read an env var?
3. If 1 is not possible, can we configure the app in an initializer or something to say "if Rails.env.production? try to connect to production, and if you can't try to connect to production_2"?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid does not support iterating through various configurations to find a working one. Instead all MongoDB drivers perform background initialization - they don't require a present or working database to construct the client, and the queries/operations will wait for the database to provision itself.

If you want to iterate through configurations, you can write a script that does so and produces a working `mongoid.yml`, then invokes the server/console/etc.

For environment variables, see https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#erb-preprocessing.